# MPlayer command line start video at x position

Tags: command-line, bash, video, mplayer

**With MPlayer how do I start playing a video at x position?**

Hello folks, so if I want to start MPlayer at x position, what would I do?

I have been ploughing through the man page and I cannot find it.

Must be:

```
mplayer -<position I need> x name.of.video.mp4
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suspect that you will be happy with `mplayer -ss 60 video.mp4`?

Comment: Very happy, how did I miss that?  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the `-ss xx` option of MPlayer. The setting uses seconds and thus to start your video 60 seconds in the following would suffice:

```
mplayer -ss 60 video.mp4
```

If you were interested in transferring allegiance to mpv (as I have) you will find the mpv option `--start` is *much more* fully featured than MPlayer's `-ss` option...